# Using intent filters with broadcastReceivers Android

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

please how is the correct way to use broadcastReceiver in concert with Intent filters..
In my android_manifest.xml file I have those lines:

```
        <activity android:name=".DataDisplayActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar" android:icon="@drawable/icon_3d" android:label="AdvancedHyperXPositiveSuperFluousApp">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.simekadam.blindassistant.UPDATE_GPS_UI"/>
            <action android:name="com.simekadam.blindassistant.UPDATE_CONTEXT_UI"/> 
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        </activity>
```

And in the activity I set the receiver with this function

```
    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, null);
```

It fails on the null, obvi it needs the IntentFilter to be set and I can add it inline as param to the function, but I asking, how to use it with XML defined intent filters..Thank for your help

Teaser: I actually got it working with the inline set intent, but I am asking how to make it working with the intent set in XML..

Answer (score 17, accepted):

you dont need to define intent-filters in your xml when you are using *registerReceiver* to receive broadcasts.

In your case, you should create a class which extends to *BroadcastReceiver* and then define that class file in your android's manifest file. for example:

class file:

```
package your.package.name;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MyCustomReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        if(action.equals("com.simekadam.blindassistant.UPDATE_GPS_UI")){
            //do something
        }
        else if(action.equals("com.simekadam.blindassistant.UPDATE_CONTEXT_UI")){
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

and addition in manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".MyCustomReceiver" android:enabled="true">
     <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.simekadam.blindassistant.UPDATE_GPS_UI" />
        <action android:name="com.simekadam.blindassistant.UPDATE_CONTEXT_UI" />
     </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: Got it..Haven't had the receiver wrapper in my xml..:) Thank you

Answer (score 5):

You can either register your receiver and intent-filters in manifest.xml as explained above or you can do both of these things dynamically as:

```
Myreceiver reMyreceive = new Myreceiver();
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("actionname");
registerReceiver(reMyreceive, filter);
```

where myreceiver will be your class extended broadcast receiver. You can view complete example [here](http://sohailaziz05.blogspot.com/2012/05/broadcast-receiver-two-ways-to.html).